# How to Connect PostgreSQL with VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, database-connection, pgadmin

I want to connect my VB.NET windows application with PostgreSQL 9.3
Beibg a beginner i am unable to do it through ODBC, and Npgsql

```
Dim mDAKap As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
Dim mCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
mCon.ConnectionString = "Dsn=PostgreSQL30;database=public;server=127.0.0.1;port=5432;uid=root;pwd=root"
mCon.Open()
```

I am getting error on mCon.OPen()

Please Help If my parameters are correct?

Comment: Have you seen the [.Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/)?

Comment: There's also http://www.connectionstrings.com...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got my answer from another source, Writing here for other beginners like me, to save their time:

First install ODBC driver (get it here http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)
After installing 32-bit driver::

```
Dim MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
MyCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=database_name;server=127.0.0.1;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=postgres;password=password;"

MyCon.Open()
        If mCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            MsgBox("Connected To PostGres", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground)
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PostgresQL 16.2` and `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022` (64 bits) I use following lines to open a database and to get database's version

```
    Public cn As NpgsqlConnection

    Private Sub OpenDataBase()
        Dim cs As String 'ConnectionString

        cs = "Server=127.0.0.1:5434;Database=extraits;Userid=postgres;Password='********'"

        cn = New NpgsqlConnection(cs)
        Try
            cn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Dim sSQL = "SELECT version()"
        Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(sSQL, cn)
        Dim dr As NpgsqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        Dim sVersion As String = dr.Item(0)
        Console.WriteLine("PostgreSQL VERSION: " & sVersion)
        dr.Close()
    End Sub
```

This code works well with `npgsql` Nuget package version 7.0.0 and 8.0.0.